# Inserting unneeded rows PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've been working on writing a small database class to help with some of the interaction I need, for some reason I have run into a problem where whenever I run the insert function, the data is inserted 7 times.

I've rewritten the function a number of times trying different methods of inserting but cannot seem to find a working one.

Here is the class:

```
class Database extends PDO {

    public function __construct($info) {
        try {
            parent::__construct('mysql:dbname=' . $info['database'] . ';host=' . $info['hostname'], $info['username'], $info['password'], array());
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function describe($table) {
        $this->run("DESCRIBE $table", array())->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 

    public function run($sql, $params = array()) {
        $run = $this->prepare($sql);
        $run->execute($params);
        return $run;    
    }

    public function insert($table, $data) {
        $vals = array_map(function($val) {
            return ':' . $val;
        }, array_keys($data));
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (' . implode(', ', array_keys($data)) . ') VALUES (' . implode(', ', $vals) . ')';
        $this->run($sql, $data);
    }

}
```

Implementation:

```
$database = new Database(Config::get('mysql'));
$data = array(
    'id' => null,
    'email' => 'user@user.com',
    'password' => 'password123',
    'name' => 'name',
    'address' => 'NYC',
    'status' => 0,
    'note' => 'admin'
);
$database->insert('users', $data);
```

Database Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `email` text,
     `password` text,
     `name` text,
     `address` text,
     `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `note` text,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Keep in mind connecting to the database and running normal queries i working fine.  If you need to know anything else just post below.  I appreciate you taking the time reading this.  Thanks,
Julien.

Full implementation (inserts 7 rows):

```
/*
$page = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'index';
if(file_exists('content/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        require_once 'includes/' . strtolower($class) . '.php';
    });
    Config::errors();
    $database = new Database(Config::get('mysql'));
    $database->insert('certly_users', array(
        'id' => null,
        'email' => 'user@user.com',
        'password' => 'password123',
        'name' => 'name',
        'address' => 'NYC',
        'status' => 0,
        'note' => 'admin'
    ));
    require 'content/pages/template/header.php';
    require 'content/pages/' . $page . '.php';
    require 'content/pages/template/footer.php';    
}else{
    header('location: /404');
}*/
```

Insert alone (inserts 2 rows):

```
require_once 'includes/database.php';
require_once 'includes/config.php';
Config::errors();
$database = new Database(Config::get('mysql'));
$database->insert('certly_users', array(
    'id' => null,
    'email' => 'user@user.com',
    'password' => 'password123',
    'name' => 'name',
    'address' => 'NYC',
    'status' => 0,
    'note' => 'admin'
));
```

Comment: `$vals = array_map(function($val) {` That's the culprit

Comment: How so?  If I echo out `$sql` it outputs the following: 

`INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, name, address, status, note) VALUES (:id, :email, :password, :name, :address, :status, :note)`. @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: Can you give us some more context for your implementation? I can't see anything here that would make it insert `sizeof($data)` times.

Comment: There is no context to be honest, i've been testing this code just as I showed you.  I haven't a clue what is causing this to happen.

Comment: @SamT forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values you're passing to `PDOStatement:execute()` do not match. You need to have an array with keys that match your placeholders (keys prefixed with `:` in your case), for example:

```
Array (
  ':id' => null,
  ':email' => 'user@user.com',
  // etc
)
```

Maybe not the most elegant way to do it, but here is one implementation. It goes in `Database::insert()` method, replaceing `$this->run($sql, $data);`:

```
$params = array();
foreach ($data in $k => $v) {
  $params[':' . $k] = $v;
}
$this->run($sql, $params);
```

Comment: Same result, still inserting it 7 times (the number of params).  http://pastebin.com/ubLi2k7w Thanks!

Comment: the `:` is optional so it would change anything, its funny how the number of insert matches the number of parameters. there is something you forgot to show @julienhaversano

Comment: I removed all excess code that had nothing to do with inserting, it still inserted two rows.  Post has been updated with more examples.  Thanks.  @meda